# How to clone an existing repo from github to windows pc

Tags: github

I have a repo in github.com.

I like to clone the repo to my local windows pc.

I installed git on my pc. In cmd,

```
C:\project>git clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git

Cloning into 'xxx'...
```

[image: connect to github]

When I click **"Sign in with your browser"**, I see a quick flash but nothing happens.

```
info: please complete authentication in your browser...
```

I also tried by **entering the access code**:

```
C:\project>git clone https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git
Cloning into 'xxx'...
```

Here it asks for access code. After I enter the access code:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/' not found
```

Comment: You should be able to just do `git clone http-github-address`, no need for any extra tools. I have no idea why `Sign in with your browser` window shows up. What git implementation do you use?

Comment: What do you mean by what git implementation?